# $.ajax script not pulling php data into div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, include

I've spent the last couple of days wrestling with a .hover script that posts data to a php script then retrieves related data from a database.

Posting id data to the details.inc.php page is working fine. An alert in the script retrieves and show's the data correctly.

The problem arises when i try to include the data in a div, nothing seems to happen. Firefox show's the script to be executing and retrieving the correct id info as it should.
I don't know where from here. I've tried all i can, but my understanding of java is limited
Thanks for any help in advance.

A mouse over function executes and retrieves the id from an image

```
<img src="#" class="latest"  id="id_retrieved_from_DB">
```

id is then passed through jquery and ajax which retrieves data linked to id from details.inc.php, the data retrieved should then be included in the "details" div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Mouse over
    $(function(){
        $('.latest').hover(function() {
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
        cache: false,
                url: "details.inc.php",
                data: 'hovered_id='+id,
                success:function(data){

                alert(data);//showing data correctly

                //not working here
        $("#details").load('details.inc.php', data);
                }
            });
return false;
        }
      });
</script>
```

details.inc.php

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/userauthentication_conn.php'); ?>
<?php 
require_once('../../includes/session_remap.inc');
require_once('../../includes/tNG_functions.inc.php');
?>

<?php
$KTColParam1_rsDetails = "0";
if (isset($_GET["hovered_id"])) {
  $KTColParam1_rsDetails = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET["hovered_id"] : addslashes($_GET["hovered_id"]);
}
mysql_select_db($database_userauthentication_conn, $userauthentication_conn);
$query_rsDetails = sprintf("SELECT tbl_entries.id_ent, tbl_entries.country_ent, tbl_entries.date_ent, tbl_entries.title_ent, tbl_entries.subject_ent, tbl_entries.description_ent, tbl_entries.image_ent, tbl_entries.url_ent FROM tbl_entries WHERE (tbl_entries.id_ent=%s) ORDER BY tbl_entries.date_ent DESC ", $KTColParam1_rsDetails);
$rsDetails = mysql_query($query_rsDetails, $userauthentication_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDetails);
$totalRows_rsDetails = mysql_num_rows($rsDetails);
?>
<!-- Details -->
<a href="<?php echo $row_rsDetails['url_ent']; ?>" title="Go to <?php echo $row_rsDetails['title_ent']; ?>">
<?php
    //show if file exists
    if (file_exists("../../images/entries/" . $row_rsDetails['id_ent'] . "__img.jpg")) {
  ?>
  <img src="../../images/entries/<?php echo $row_rsDetails['id_ent']; ?>__img.jpg" width="70" height="70">
  <?php
    }
    //end show if file exists
  ?>
<p class="seriesName"><?php echo $row_rsDetails['subject_ent']; ?></p>
<h4 class="programTitle"><?php echo $row_rsDetails['title_ent']; ?></h4>
</a>
<!-- End -->
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsDetails);
?>
```

Comment: what does `alert(data)` output?

Comment: This `$("#details").load('details.inc.php', data);` looks very wrong. Have you checked the manual on load? You probably want to do something else there. Could you state what your expected result is? $.ajax and $.load are certainly doing similar ajax jobs here. The second isn't right.

Comment: Hi I have tried a number if different alternative, as far as i can tell the correct code should be $("#details").html(data); but i get no joy from that either

Comment: <!-- Details --> <a href="url 2" title="Go to test 2"> <img src="../../images/entries/3__img.jpg" width="70" height="70"> <p class="seriesName">Recipe</p> <h4 class="programTitle">test 2</h4> </a> <!-- End -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing a second ajax call?

If you already have the data available in javascript, you can replace:

```
$("#details").load('details.inc.php', data);
```

with:

```
$("#details").html(data);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer. I already tried what you are suggesting with no success. I'm confused as it make no sense why its not working.

Comment: @user2166874 Can you add the output of `console.log(data);` in the success callback of your ajax function to your question. This should work.

Comment: [22:43:32.879] <!-- Details -->
<a href="url 2" title="Go to test 2">
  <img src="../../images/entries/3__img.jpg" width="70" height="70">
  <p class="seriesName">Recipe</p>
<h4 class="programTitle">test 2</h4>
</a>
<!-- End -->
This is also what the alert throws out

Comment: @user2166874 Do you have an html element with the ID of `details` in your page?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out that i had identified the details div with a 'class' instead of an 'id' so i just had to change the #hash to a dot. $(".details").html(data);

Answer (score 0):

if $("#details") is in the script page and that's the div you wish to display the result, you could use only load:

```
//Mouse over
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$("#details").load('details.inc.php', 'hovered_id='+id, function(data){alert(data);});
```

Or you could use $.get()

Jquery manual
The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

And your PHP script uses get.

Comment: Surprised. good you have an answer. Usually, it is best to let's know the error you get. Sometimes, it might be how you use the code.